# Django - import constants's variable from variable

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-import

I've a Django application and I'd like to import from myapp.constants the MYCONSTANT variable in a way that myapp and MYCONSTANT is stored in a variable:

```
VAR1='myapp'
VAR2='MYCONSTANT'
```

and I'd like to import it using the variables.

```
from VAR1.constants import VAR2
```

, but of course it does not work.

How can I achieve this? Is there any similar way to using apps.get_model() ?

---

I need to use the VAR1 and VAR2 variables as they're unknown to me, they're coming from somewhere else. Let's say, they're parameters of a function. I could probably solve it with exec, but I really would like to avoid using exec.

Comment: Add a `.env` file to set your environment vars prior to starting django. They will be loaded automatically and you can reference them as you like. Se here for a tutorial: https://djangocentral.com/environment-variables-in-django/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it solve your problem?

```py
  def get_constant_value(module_name, constant):
      try:
           module = importlib.import_module(f'{module_name}.constants')
      except Exception as e:
           raise e
      return getattr(module, constant)

 constant_value = get_constant_value(VAR1, VAR2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new app with the name you want, say APP_NAME:

```
$ python manage.py startapp APP_NAME
```

Register the app in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',

    'APP_NAME',      # Append to the bottom
]
```

Create a new `constants.py` file in your `APP_NAME` module. Place you **constants** in constants.py Like:

```
VAR1='myapp'
VAR2='MYCONSTANT'
```

Now, you can access `VAR2` by importing:

```
from APP_NAME.constants import VAR2
```

Comment: When you put the ***APP_NAME*** in  **`INSTAllED_APPS`**, must be enclosed with quotes, that is, it should be a string

Comment: Yes... Absolutely. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: i was not clear with my question, but i put some extra informations there (below the ``-----'' )

Comment: That means, you can just append at the below `APP_NAME` . This(`....`) means that there are other contents.

Comment: If i'd use **from myapp.constants import MYCONSTANT**, that'd work. The setup is not the issue. The problem is that I don't know the name of the model and the name of the variable which needs to be imported, and this is why they're stored in a variable.